# ¿JDialog desde MVC?

Tags: java, mvc, dialog

Estoy realizando una app, en el cual manejo la arquitectura MVC, en la clase controlador de un JDialog, quiero mandar a llamar a otro JDialog, al momento de poner los parámetros de los constructores da error.
Es correcto que si lo llamo desde el mismo JDialog, seria fácil poniendo (new javax.swing.JDialog()), pero si lo llamo desde la clase controlador me dice que no se puede convertir a frame, supongo que los parametros estan mal, al menos que no sea correcto instancia una nueva vista desde la clase controlador?
Anexo código del botón del Dialog principal

```
if (e.getSource() == admin.Pass) {
     segundoDialog sd = new segundoDialog(new javax.swing.JDialog(), true);
     sd.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: que tal, Code_Serv, seria de mucha utilidad que pasaras el codigo de tu clase segundoDialog, ya que en el codigo que has provisto no se puede apreciar el problema.

Comment: Ha sido resuelto gracias